# How to define a column of a dataframe using conditions based on its own previous values?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a data-frame, `df` as below, that has a 'Value' column which I'd like to apply some boolean analysis too.

```
date     Value 
10/11    0.798
11/11    1.235
12/11    0.890
13/11    0.756
14/11    0.501
...
```

Essentially, I'd like to create a new column that switches to `TRUE` when the value is greater than 1, and remains true unless the value drops below 0.75. For example, it would look like the below using `df`:

```
column
FALSE
TRUE
TRUE
TRUE
FALSE
```

I am struggling to find an appropriate way to reference the previous value of a column I am defining without running into some error. The logic I want to use is as below:

`df['column'] = (df['value'] >= 1) | ((df['column'].shift(1) == True) & (df['value'] >= 0.75))`

Is there a way that I can achieve this without over-complicating things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
val1, val2 = 1, 0.75

out = (df.assign(
    new=df.Value.where(df.Value.gt(val1) | df.Value.lt(val2))
    .ffill().gt(val1)))

print(out)
```

Output:

```
    date  Value    new
0  10/11  0.798  False
1  11/11  1.235   True
2  12/11  0.890   True
3  13/11  0.756   True
4  14/11  0.501  False
```

Comment: I knew some type of 'ffill' would come in handy, although I am following your instructions exactly and I cannot seem to see the newly assigned 'signal' column when I print the data-frame afterwards. No specific error comes up, but there is also no new column. Do you know what could be going on?

Comment: Please, see my edited solution: Everything should now work fine on your side, @vicefreak04!

Answer (score 2):

Actually calling function with apply might help, with some "remembering" logic.

```
res = True

def CheckRow(row):
    global res
    if res == True:
        if row['value']>1.0:
            res = False #next time check for < 0.75
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else: #res == False
        if row['value']<0.75:
            res = True #next time check for above 1.0
            return False
        else:
            return True

df['column'] = df.apply(lambda x: CheckRow(x), axis = 1)
```

Comment: Following this method, I attain the following error: "NameError: name 'res' is not defined". Not sure why this is coming up as I assign 'res = True' before the function is defined as in your example. Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: Which row is throwing error? Do you have code properly indented?